# Summing by month in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I've been trying different things for a couple of days to summarise transactions by month (I'm not so interested in which year, just by month).

When I got the result it differs from the one I have in Excel and Tableau so I don't understand what is the problem.

I used the following two queries which gave me the same result however a different one from Tableau and Excel which both show other figures:

```
SELECT extract(MONTH from TRAN_D) as month, sum(TRAN_A) as total_value 
FROM royal_bank_aus.tran
GROUP BY month;

SELECT year(TRAN_D),month(TRAN_D),sum(TRAN_A)
FROM royal_bank_aus.tran
GROUP BY year(TRAN_D),month(TRAN_D)
ORDER BY year(TRAN_D),month(TRAN_D);
```

Comment: Both queries look correct. How do you get the result in Excel? Do you access the same database or are you working with a copy of the data?

Comment: Can you make your example more clear, can you give some sample data and sample results?

Comment: I think that the problem was when I exported the data as an Excel file and for some reason the rows were less. When I  expored the file in CSV format it was fine and correct. Thanks for your comments. I don't know why there was this issue with the excel file.